# Using Linux Top, How do I view the thread count of a process

Tags: top

With `ps` I can view the *NLWP (number light weight processes)* with `ps -o NLWP`.  How do I show this column in **top**?  Only interested in the count.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/892/is-there-a-way-to-see-details-of-all-the-threads-that-a-process-has-in-linux/901

Answer (score 4):

Hit 'f' and select nTH to view the number of threads.

Comment: Could you explain how you got to this answer?